# More pythonic way to iterate

Tags: refactoring, iterator, python

I am using a module that is part of a commercial software API.  The good news is there is a python module - the bad news is that its pretty unpythonic.

To iterate over rows, the follwoing syntax is used:

```
cursor = gp.getcursor(table)
row =  cursor.next()
while row:
    #do something with row
    row = cursor.next()
```

What is the most pythonic way to deal with this situation?  I have considered creating a first class function/generator and wrapping calls to a for loop in it:

```
def cursor_iterator(cursor):
    row =  cursor.next()
    while row:
        yield row
        row = cursor.next()

[...]

cursor = gp.getcursor(table)
for row in cursor_iterator(cursor):
    # do something with row
```

This is an improvement, but feels a little clumsy.  Is there a more pythonic approach?  Should I create a wrapper class around the `table` type?

Comment: Mmmh `cursor.next()` looks like you *might* be able to do `for row in cursor:`

Comment: @Felix, nope.  `next` doesn't raise a [`StopIteration`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration), so after the real data, that would just loop forever with `row` being `None`.

Comment: @Felix King: Almost, but because an iterator signals termination by raising StopIteration, `for row in cursor:` will iterate over the rows, then give an infinite stream of `None`s.

Comment: @Matthew, @Paul: Ok :) Thank you, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that one of Next and next is a typo and they're both the same, you can use the not-so-well-known variant of the built-in iter function:

```
for row in iter(cursor.next, None):
    <do something>
```

Comment: Great answer! Yep, the functions are the same (worse still, they are somehow case insensitive!).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom wrapper like:

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self, gp, table):
        self.gp = gp
        self.table = table
        self.cursor = None

   def __iter__(self):
        self.cursor = self.gp.getcursor(self.table)
        return self

   def next(self):
        n = self.cursor.next()
        if not n:
             raise StopIteration()
        return n
```

and then:

```
for row in Table(gp, table)
```

*See also: [Iterator Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter)*

Comment: I like this approach also.  I might consider wrapping `gp` in this manner if I need to wrap more than just the cursor iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a Python iterator interface around the `table` object, imho:

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self, table):
         self.table = table

    def rows(self):
        cursor = gp.get_cursor(self.table)
        row =  cursor.Next()
        while row:
            yield row
            row = cursor.next()
```

Now you just call:

```
my_table = Table(t)
for row in my_table.rows():
     # do stuff with row
```

It's very readable, in my opinion.